# Get DNS name by computer name C# AD

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a DNS name field from Active Directory in my C# Windows Forms application.
I have a computer name, and I wants to get the DNS name of this computer from Active directory. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS name is stored in an attribute called `dNSHostName` on the AD object for the computer, so you need to find the object in AD and read that attribute.

Here's an example, where the variable `computerName` has the computer name.

```
var search = new DirectorySearcher {
    Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=computer)(sAMAccountName={computerName}$))"
};
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dNSHostName");
var result = search.FindOne();

var dnsName = result.Properties["dNSHostName"][0].ToString();
```

I'm not setting `SearchRoot` in the `DirectorySearcher` here, so this will only search the current domain you're logged into.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Do I really need this `$` sign? And if yes, can you tell why? then how I can determine {0} instead of {computerName} then passing the vairiable that store the value? For example, I tried to do `String.Format($"..thepath with {0} instead of computerName", comp)` but I am sure this is the wrong syntax. Can you help?

Comment: The `$` before the `"` is [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings), which was introduced in C# 6. You use it *instead* of `String.Format`. So in your example, you would use `$"..thepath with {comp} instead of computerName"`

Comment: Note that there is also a `$` at the end of the computer name in the LDAP query. That is because the `sAMAccountName` attribute of computer objects do actually end with `$`.